# How to update Web component DOM when child elements are rendered via an array loop

Tags: web-component, lit

I have created a web component using [lit](https://lit.dev/).

The component has a parent lit element and a child lit element. The parent has an array of child elements and inside its render function, it iterates the array and renders the children.

Assume the array has 5 elements and If I remove the 3rd element from the array. Then the 4th and the 5th child elements get updated, which I do not expect. Below is the code.

What I want is to get the 3rd element removed, but no update for the 4th and 5th elements. How can I do that

```
@customElement('parent')
export class Parent extends LitElement {
render() {
    return html`
        ${this.property.children.map((property: any) =>
                html`
                    <child .properties=${property} id=${property.id}></child>`)} `;
-     }

 removeChild() {
  this.property.children.splice(2, 1);
  this.requestUpdate();
}

@property({type: Object})
private property: any = {};
}

@customElement('child')
    export class Child extends LitElement {
     render() {
    return html`
        <label>"${this.properties.id}"</label> `;
-     }
}
```